# EntityFramework 6: создать Identity Key

Tags: entity-framework

Здравствуйте.

Объявил класс. Поле `public string Id { get; set; } - primary Key`
Как сделать так, чтобы при добавлении новой записи база его генерировала сама?

`[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`  - не помогает! Ключ не становится `Identity`

Comment: @Сергей Полушин, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Исправил тип на int.
Если поставить
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)], то первая запись запишется с Id=0. Последующая попытка добавить запись выдаст ошибку, мол нельзя добавить повторяющееся значение id=0.
Если исправить на [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)], то ошибка гласит о том, что в поле id нельзя записать значение null.
Вот это прикол. В первом случае генерирует всегда 0, во втором - ничего не генерирует.

Comment: @Сергей Полушин, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена!
При [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] была ошибка о том, что поле Id не может быть равно значению Null. Т.е. это значение не генерировалось.

Внимание, решение:

[Key, DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]

И всё работает! Значение при добавлении новой записи генерируется автоматически. Может кто расскажет почему так и в чем разница?

Comment: это уже другой вопрос

Answer (score 3):

Зачем вам в базе. По умолчание EF сама все сгенерирует. Только почему у вас свойство ID типа string, измените его на int например.

Т.е. вы создаете сущность. Например, класс:

```
class Person
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Далее создаете класс контекста, и EF сделает все за вас. Т.е. создаст таблицу для хранения данной сущности и свойство ID сделает первичным ключом.

Comment: Хорошо, рассмотрим случай с int.

В таком случае добавление новой записи будет выглядеть так:

var newperson = new Person { Name="Name" };

db.Persons.Add(newperson);

это будет работать?

Сейчас попробую и отпишусь.

String потому что в стандартных таблицах пользователей тип уникальных полей - string

Comment: > String потому что в стандартных таблицах пользователей тип уникальных полей - string

Первый раз сталкиваюсь с тем, чтобы поле ID было типа string. На моей практике это либо uniqueidentifier, либо int 

> В таком случае добавление новой записи будет выглядеть так:

var newperson = new Person { Name="Name" };
db.Persons.Add(newperson);

это будет работать?

Да будет, если тип поля поставите норальный.

Comment: В VisualStudio при создании веб-приложения есть заготовка, в которой реализована авторизация пользователей. В базе присутствуют таблицы учетных записей пользователей и ролей. Там все поля Id - типа string.
Ну да ладно, пока нет нужды в этом разбираться.

Comment: Что касается нашего ключа типа int:
Изменил тип на int. В serverExplorer открываю базу, нахожу нужную таблицу, правой кнопкой -> Open Table Definition. Да, поле Id PRIMARY KEY, но не Identity. Ладно, в том же ServerExplorer у этой таблицы разворачиваю список полей, выделяю Id. В окне Properties вижу свойство "Is Identity" равное false(изменить нельзя). Ну ладно, вдруг EF сам генерирует новый Id и туда его запишет. Запускаю приложение, при добавлении записи и вызове метода Db.SaveChanges(); получаю ошибку: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id'...column does not allow nulls. INSERT fail

Comment: Если делать так: var newperson = new Person { Id = 0; Name="Name" };
То первый раз запись добавится, поле Id будет равно 0. Второй раз заругается на то, что не может вставить значение Id, которое уже есть.


Ну а PRIMARY KEY и тип string делался

Comment: я может не совсем понимаю что должно быть в классе контекста?
Вообще когда я описал класс, для которого нужно было создать таблицу в БД, я кликнул вызвал контекстное меню папки Models и нажал добавить контроллер, используя EF. Указал существующий контекст БД. Получил контроллер и представления. В существующем контексте получил новое объявление: public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MyWebApp.Models.Person> Persons { get; set; }

Все правильно? Или что-то пропустил?

Comment: > Если делать так: var newperson = new Person { Id = 0; Name="Name" }; То первый раз запись добавится.

При добавление новой записи не обязательно указывать ID = 0. Т.к. 0 это значение по умолчанию, кроме того EF сама заботиться об  ID.

Т.е. чтобы добавить новую запись вы просто пишите: context.People.Add(new Person() { Name = "Вася"}); Далее на контексте вызываете context.SaveChanges(); И все добавляется и сохраняется.

Comment: Пример простого контекста.

public class EFDbContext : DbContext
{
   public DbSet<Person> People{ get; set; }
}

Comment: Где People это название таблицы, в которой хранятся ваши Person.

Answer (score 2):

Если у вас тип ключа string то как он может быть автоматически гененрируемым? Скажем, для целочисленных ключей логика понятна - сначала  1, затем 2, 3, 4 и так далее. А что по-вашему должно генерироваться в случае если это строка? Строки в отличие от int неисчисляемы

Comment: String потому что в стандартных таблицах пользователей тип уникальных полей - string

Comment: А что это за стандартные таблицы такие? Как я понял, вы используете ASP.NET MVC младше 4 версии?

Comment: >String потому что в стандартных таблицах пользователей тип уникальных полей - string

эмм..что это за глупость?

Comment: Использую ASP.NET MVC 4 версии. Создаем новый проект ASP.NET WEb Application. В диалоге выбора шаблона выбираем MVC. Там же есть кнопка "Change Authentication", по умолчанию выбрано "Individual User Accounts". Получаем проект с реализованной аутентификацией. В БД присутствует ряд соответствующих таблиц. Например, таблица AspNetRoles имеет следующее объявление: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetRoles] ( [Id]   NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,[Name] NVARCHAR (256) NOT NULL,CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetRoles] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)); При работе с контекстом БД так же убедитесь, что поле Id имеет тип strin